# How do I declare static member that should be used between several subs in vb6 ?

Tags: vb6

I'm getting mad of visual basic 6.

How do I declare

```
static counter as int
```

That may be used between several subs in a class module?

I can't declare it inside class module - vb6 tells me that: *Invalid outside procedure*
If I declare it inside procedure - it's invisible from other procedures (subs)

Comment: `Static` is procedure level scope only, but preserved between calls. A module/class level variable will have a wider scope, but will also be per class instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `Dim` it at Module scope.  Module scoped variables persist.